# 'Error 1292: Incorrect datetime value' from mysql using QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime() in pyqt5

Tags: mysql, pyqt5

I was having this error when trying to insert datetime in mysql.

mysql column inv_date datatype is timestamp(6) while i am using QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime() to retrieve currect date and time from my computer. What could have been the correct format and code in pyqt5?

Thank you in advance!

Here's the full code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QMessageBox
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore    import pyqtSlot
import MySQLdb as mdb
import datetime
import math

currentDT = datetime.datetime.now

from A3AMainWindow import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.btn_inv_save.setEnabled(False)
        self.btn_inv_cancel.setEnabled(False)
        self.dt_inv_datetime.setDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime())
        self.de_inv_expiry.setDate(QtCore.QDate.currentDate())
        self.de_inv_duedate.setDate(QtCore.QDate.currentDate())

        self.initWindow()


    def initWindow(self):
        self.le_inv_invnum.textChanged.connect(self.newText)
        self.le_inv_supplier.textChanged.connect(self.newText)

        self.le_inv_batch.textChanged.connect(self.newText)

        self.le_inv_quantity.textChanged.connect(self.newText)
        self.le_inv_listprice.textChanged.connect(self.newText)
        self.le_inv_discount.textChanged.connect(self.newText)
        self.le_inv_netprice.textChanged.connect(self.newText)
        self.le_inv_totalamount.textChanged.connect(self.newText)


        self.btn_inv_save.clicked.connect(self.click_save)
        self.btn_inv_cancel.clicked.connect(self.Cancel)



    def Cancel(self):
        self.dt_inv_datetime.setDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime())
        self.le_inv_invnum.setText('')
        self.le_inv_supplier.setText('')
        self.cb_inv_prodname.setItemText(0,'Eprex 4kiu')
        self.te_inv_itemdesc.setText('')
        self.le_inv_batch.setText('')
        self.de_inv_expiry.setDate(QtCore.QDate.currentDate())
        self.le_inv_quantity.setText('')
        self.le_inv_listprice.setText('')
        self.le_inv_discount.setText('')
        self.le_inv_netprice.setText('')
        self.le_inv_totalamount.setText('')
        self.cb_inv_terms.setItemText(0,'COD')
        self.de_inv_duedate.setDate(QtCore.QDate.currentDate())
        self.cb_inv_status.setItemText(0,'Fully Paid')       

    def newText(self):
        if self.le_inv_invnum.text() and self.le_inv_supplier.text() and self.le_inv_batch.text() and self.le_inv_quantity.text() and self.le_inv_listprice.text() and self.le_inv_discount.text() and self.le_inv_netprice.text() and self.le_inv_totalamount.text():
            self.btn_inv_save.setEnabled(True)
            self.btn_inv_cancel.setEnabled(True)
            self.btn_inv_edit.setEnabled(False)
            self.btn_inv_prev.setEnabled(False)
            self.btn_inv_next.setEnabled(False)
            self.btn_inv_search.setEnabled(False)

        else:
            self.btn_inv_save.setEnabled(False)
            self.btn_inv_cancel.setEnabled(False)
            self.btn_inv_edit.setEnabled(True)
            self.btn_inv_prev.setEnabled(True)
            self.btn_inv_next.setEnabled(True)
            self.btn_inv_search.setEnabled(True)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def click_save(self):
        con = mdb.connect(user='root', passwd='ilovemy1god',
                        host='localhost', database='A3A_SIS')
        with con:
            cur = con.cursor()

            cur.execute('''INSERT INTO inv_delivery(inv_date, inv_invoice_num, inv_sup_name, inv_prod_name, inv_prod_itemdesc, inv_batchnum, inv_expiry, inv_quantity, inv_list_price, inv_discount, inv_net_price, inv_total_amount, inv_pay_terms, inv_due_date, inv_status)
                            VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)''',
                            ( self.dt_inv_datetime.dateTime(),
                              self.le_inv_invnum.text(),
                              self.le_inv_supplier.text(),
                              self.cb_inv_prodname.currentIndex(),
                              self.te_inv_itemdesc.document(),
                              self.le_inv_batch.text(),
                              self.de_inv_expiry.date(),
                              self.le_inv_quantity.text(),
                              self.le_inv_listprice.text(),
                              self.le_inv_discount.text(),
                              self.le_inv_netprice.text(),
                              self.le_inv_totalamount.text(),
                              self.cb_inv_terms.currentIndex(),
                              self.de_inv_duedate.date(),
                              self.cb_inv_status.currentIndex()

                              )
                            )

            cur.close()
            QMessageBox.information(self, "Connection", "Data Inserted Successfully")

        self.dt_inv_datetime.setDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime())
        self.le_inv_invnum.setText('')
        self.le_inv_supplier.setText('')
        self.cb_inv_prodname.setItemText(0,'Eprex 4kiu')
        self.te_inv_itemdesc.setText('')
        self.le_inv_batch.setText('')
        self.de_inv_expiry.setDate(QtCore.QDate.currentDate())
        self.le_inv_quantity.setText('')
        self.le_inv_listprice.setText('')
        self.le_inv_discount.setText('')
        self.le_inv_netprice.setText('')
        self.le_inv_totalamount.setText('')
        self.cb_inv_terms.setItemText(0,'COD')
        self.de_inv_duedate.setDate(QtCore.QDate.currentDate())
        self.cb_inv_status.setItemText(0,'Fully Paid')

        self.initWindow()




if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = MainWindow()
    #ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    #ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Since you are not completely new in SO, you should already know that the best way to get people _take a look_ at your question you need to include some code samples, input and output. In this case, print the datetime value you are sending **before** you send it. As a general walk around, you may try sending a string of the form 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` (hour in 24 range). Many DBMSs would accept automatic conversion from this string to a binary datetime.

Comment: okay will edit it. Here's the error im getting: OperationalError: (1292, "Incorrect datetime value: 'PyQt5.QtCore.QDateTime(2018, 5, 24, 18, 53, 17, 705)' for column 'inv_date' at row 1")

Comment: Assign the value of `PyQt5.QtCore.QDateTime(2018, 5, 24, 18, 53, 17, 705)` to a variable and print the variable.

Comment: can you give an example and how can i insert it in mysql? really sorry im new to this.

Comment: Before I engage into that, I would like you to perform the test I suggested (print).

Comment: Okay i will. will post it here once im done. thank you again!

Comment: I got it already! I used the expression 'toString(QtCore.Qt.ISODate)' to convert qdatetime to string. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: My pleasure. Will appreciate if you up-vote any of my comments that was helpful for you.

Comment: i wonder how to do that? cant find that option. sorry really new in so.

Comment: Simple. If you move your mouse to the left of a comment, two small icons will show (in gray): an up arrow and a flag. Click on the up arrow.

Comment: i think im not yet allowed since im very new in so. theres no up vote or down vote at the left side of the comment

Comment: OK. I'll put my comments as an answer and you will be able to mark the answer. One minute...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to debug by printing the value of `PyQt5.QtCore.QDateTime(2018, 5, 24, 18, 53, 17, 705)`.

As a general walk around, you may try sending a string of the form 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` (hour in 24 range). Many DBMSs would accept automatic conversion from this string to a binary datetime.

Comment: Thank you also for the help!

Comment: It was my pleasure.